# How to continue the requests library function after receiving the error using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, error-handling, python-requests

i wanna writing a error_handler function with python

```
def error_handler(url_list1):
  try:
    resp = requests.get(url_list1, headers = HEADERS, timeout = 3)
    resp.raise_for_status()

  except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)

  except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc)

  except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)

  except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("Ops: Something Else Wrong!",err)

  return resp
```

I want to this code to keep working after it cathes an error
But `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment`  i took this error and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your code fail in the try block, then the `resp` variable in the return is not assigned. To keep it running, you must put the return statement inside the `try` block.

```py
def error_handler(url_list1):
  try:
    resp = requests.get(url_list1, headers = HEADERS, timeout = 3)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    return resp

  except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)

  except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc)

  except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)

  except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("Ops: Something Else Wrong!",err)
```

This will solve the current problem. I don't know if other ones will follow.